# Flexbox inside another flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get a flexbox working inside a flexbox. While the first (wrapping) flexbox works, the one inside does nothing. Is there anyway to get this to work?

What I'm looking to do is effectively have two sticky footers and have the height of both reach the the footers.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;  /* to avoid scrollbars */
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;  /* use the flex model */
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;  /* learn more: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/ */
}

#header {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;  /* can be variable as well */
  
}

#body {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  height: 100%:
}
#wrapper2 {
  display: flex;  /* use the flex model */
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#body2 {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  flex: 1;
}
#footer2 {
  background: red;
  flex: 0;
}

#footer{
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="body">Bodyof<br/>
    variable<br/>
    height<br/>
    <div id="wrapper2">
    <div id="body2">
    blah
    </div>
    <div id="footer2">
    blah<br />
    blah
    </div>    
    </div>
    </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer<br/>
    of<br/>
    variable<br/>
    height<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shixma/np3dnkk2/)

Comment: I think all the  problem you have is HTML, if you move footer 2 out of the #wrapper2. it will work TA

Comment: The problem is probably from wrapper2 div. You set its min height to 100% but it isn't stretching to footer, and that's why the second footer isn't at the bottom. You might have to give it minimum height in px for the flex to work.

Comment: Setting the min-height in px would defeat the purpose of the flexbox. What i want is for both bodys to extend down to the bottom but resize themselves as well if the window height changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there. Just two steps away:

1. Make `#body` a flex container.
2. Give `.wrapper2` full height with `flex: 1`.

(I also got rid of percentage heights. You don't need them.)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#header {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
#body {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display: flex;            /* new */
  flex-direction: column;   /* new */
}
#wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;                  /* new */
}
#body2 {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  flex: 1;
}
#footer2 {
  background: red;
}
#footer {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="body">
    Bodyof
    <br>variable
    <br>height
    <br>
    <div id="wrapper2">
      <div id="body2">blah</div>
      <div id="footer2">
        blah
        <br>blah
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer
    <br>of
    <br>variable
    <br>height
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/np3dnkk2/1/)

Once the adjustments above are made, you can pin the inner (red) footer to the bottom with:

- `flex: 1` on `#body2`, which is what you have, or
- `margin-bottom: auto` on `#body2`, or
- `margin-top: auto` on `#footer2`, or
- `justify-content: space-between` on the container (`#wrapper2`)