# Browser support for Flexbox inside of another flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've spent a whole day trying to make this work.
While I am able to use one flex box, it becomes a hassle when a flex box shall contain another flex box.

I've tried to follow the hints from this question: 
[Flexbox inside another flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195456/flexbox-inside-another-flexbox)

It helped a little bit, but I'm still not there unfortunately.

What makes things even more confusing is that it seems like Safari and Chrome are displaying the same page totally different. This makes it even harder to understand what I am doing wrong.

What I'm trying to do is, having one outer flex box with a header and content. This outer flex box shall have another flex box inside the content, again with header and content.

It seems like the table which is located inside of the inner flex box's content does not belong to the inner flex box.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.outerFlexBox {
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* for Safari */
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* for Safari */
    background-color: green;
    border: black dotted;
}

.outerHeader {
    border: blue dotted;
}

.outerContent {
    flex: 1;
    border: red dotted;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.innerFlexBox {
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* for Safari */
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* for Safari */
    background-color: yellow;
    border: black solid;
}

.innerHeader {
    border: blue solid;
}

.innerContent {
 flex: 1;
    border: red solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.myTable {
 flex: 1;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow-y: auto;
 border: grey solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid outerFlexBox">
    <div class="outerHeader">
        <h4>Some Outer Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="outerContent">
  <p>Some outer content</p>
  <div class="innerFlexBox">
      <div class="innerHeader">
       <p>Some Inner Header</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerContent">
   <p>Some inner content</p>
   <table class="myTable">
    <thead>
     <tr><th>Some Header Column</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr><td>Some row</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Some row</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Some row</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Some row</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Some row</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Some row</td></tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is how this same page looks like on Chrome (left) and safari (right).
[image]

Comment: I've been bitten before by nested flexboxes in Safari, especially with `flex-direction: column`. This might be worth checking out: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Flexbox and take full advantage of its properties, one will get at cross browser solution.

The major part here is to drop all `height:100%;` and make use of the Flebox growth property, `flex-grow`.

Additionally, I made both `outerContent` and `innerContent` flex containers, so Flebox can take care of filling the remaining space all the way.

*Note, I have tested this with success on Chrome/Firefox/IE11/Edge*

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/80vfj12a/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;             /*  IE11 fix  */
}

.outerFlexBox {
  flex: 1;                   /*  IE11 fix  */
  min-height: 100vh;

  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* for Safari */
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  /* for Safari */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
  border: black dotted;
}

.outerHeader {
  border: blue dotted;
}

.outerContent {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: red dotted;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* for Safari */
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  /* for Safari */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.innerFlexBox {
  flex-grow: 1;

  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* for Safari */
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  /* for Safari */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: black solid;
}

.innerHeader {
  border: blue solid;
}

.innerContent {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: red solid;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* for Safari */
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  /* for Safari */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.myTable {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  border: grey solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid outerFlexBox">
  <div class="outerHeader">
    <h4>Some Outer Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="outerContent">
    <p>Some outer content</p>
    <div class="innerFlexBox">
      <div class="innerHeader">
        <p>Some Inner Header</p>
      </div>
      <div class="innerContent">
        <p>Some inner content</p>
        <table class="myTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Some Header Column</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Some row</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Some row</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Some row</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Some row</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Some row</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Some row</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They now both look same on Safari and Chrome. Thank you, LGSon! I'm a little bit confused though why the innerFlexBox still does not contain the innerContent. It looks like the innerFlexBox contains the innerHeader only. If you look at the boarders and background colors, the yellow background-color and the black, solid border from the innerFlexBox is around the innerHeader only. The innerContent has a green background-color which is from the outerFlexBox. Also, the red solid boarder of the innerContent seems to be located inside of the outerContent container. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Hans The `innerFlexBox` and `innerContent` are siblings, so the `innerFlexBox` can't _contain_ the `innerContent`, but the `innerHeader` is a child of `innerFlexBox`, hence is contained within it.

Comment: @Hans And since the `innerContent` and `innerFleBox` are siblings, they both are flex items (children) of `outerContent`

Comment: thanks for pointing that out to me. How could I have missed that ... I've moved the innerContent right below the innerHeader and now, it's almost perfect and what I want. The only thing that bothers me with your solution now is that the the innerFlexBox does not use the complete height of the outerContent container.

Comment: Here is a Screenshot of how it looks like now https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdOYb.png

Comment: @Hans Adding `flex-grow: 1;` to `.innerFlexBox` should fix that. Updated my answer

Comment: awesome!! Almost there :-) Safari still won't use the full height of the viewport as can be seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGr2u.png. Though this is probably not an issue related to flexbox. I'm accepting your answer, thanks for the help! If you know how to fix the height issue with Safari, please let me know. Also, what's not so nice is that there is an unnecessary scrollbar on Chrome now.

Comment: @Hans Updated answer again ... check now on Safari

Comment: Still the same. What seems to work though is: html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
With .outerFlexBox {
    height:100%; Now, Safari and Chrome look exactly identical, no scroll bars there and full height is utilized.

Comment: What happens now, is that if the table contains more rows than fit in the the available height, it grows and overlaps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLjLH.png. Adding overflow-y: auto; to the table won't help.

Comment: @Hans I made yet another update. Does it work on Safari?